# How to immediately serve a custom error page on Amazon ELB 502 response?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I would like to have a custom "under maintenance" page show up if my webservers on EC2 go down.

My current setup 2 A records on Route 53, using DNS Failover with a static page as the secondary and the ELB instance as the primary.

The problem with this is DNS caching - when the server first goes down, the default 502 error appears for a while for clients who were recently on the page. It takes around 5 minutes for our custom maintenance page to show up for them. When the servers come back up, it also takes around 5 minutes for the maintenance page to go away.

The first problem is more pressing for me - I don't want users to see a plain "502 Bad Gateway" message, ever. If they visit our site and things are broken or down, they should always see our custom maintenance HTML page, regardless of whether the ELB targets went down half a second ago or 10 minutes ago.

How can I make it so that if my ELB instance returns a 502, the users will automatically see a custom error page 100% of the time, so that they never see the default "502 Bad Gateway" error page?

Comment: I've half solved this problem. For planned maintenance, I can temporarily add an ELB rule that redirects all GET requests to a target group which points to a lambda function that just returns my maintenance page as static html. This seems generally effective, but isn't useful if my webservers go down unintentionally.

Comment: So your question is "how to identify intentional downtime?" programmatically now. If it's always the same time of the day, then you can configure LB statically. If you need dynamic logic, then mark downtime somehow so that you can check it - you can do it since you intentionally terminate instances yourself.

Comment: If you're using an ALB, you can create a rule that will return a static response, and put the text of the response right in the rule. That will save you having to create the Lambda function. However, that doesn't solve the original problem, which is replacing the 502 page with a custom page, a feature that I (and many others) are waiting on. It shouldn't be that hard -- you can already configure fixed HTML responses, so just add some conditions and return that fixed response when the error condition is met.

Comment: @PatrickChu Did you find a solution to this ? :) I'm having the same issue and was thinking of using cloudwatch alarm that trigger a lambda function that deletes the forward rule in the ALB and replaces it with one that redirects to the maintenence page stored in S3. But have no clue how to exactly do it or if it's even possible.

Answer (score 3):

We are trying to configure this same thing for our web application. We see the exact same enhancement request pending with AWS since a long time: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=72363&start=125&tstart=0

The other option is to use cloudfront for the whole application (not just static content) and configure custom pages for specific error codes: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/custom-error-pages-procedure.html; we don't like this option for multiple reasons, one of which is the added complexity.
So, at this time, it looks like we will have to live with this default 502 page.